# Отправка HTTP через сокеты: 400 Bad request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, сокет, python-3.7

```
import socket
import re

mysock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url=input ("Enter a url: ")
try:
    re.search("^http[s]?://.*?", url)
except:
    print ("Error")

prot, hostdoc= url.split("//")
host, doc= hostdoc.split ("/")
mysock.connect((host, 80))
cmd = 'GET url HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send (cmd)

while True:
    data=mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data)<1:
        break
    print (data.decode(), end='')

mysock.close()
```

Выдаёт ошибку в Питоне 3.7 (400 Bad request). Ссылки рабочие.

Для решения задачи можно пользоваться только socket. В чём ошибка?

Comment: url, прописанный после GET, обязан начинаться со слэша, в противном случае запрос считается некорректным

Comment: быть может `cmd = f'GET {url} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()`? [реф](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Comment: aepot, остановилась пока на вашем варианте.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавлять `/`, например: `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` (это запрос `index`), если у вас `url` будет `http://google.ru/search`, тогда `GET /search HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`.

Советую парсить `url` соответствующими инструментами, например [urlsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit).

Попробуйте так:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
import socket
import re

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = input("Enter a url: ")
try:
    re.search("^http[s]?://.*?", url)
except:
    print("Error")

result = urlsplit(url)

mysock.connect((result.netloc, 80))

cmd = f'GET {result.path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data=mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data)<1:
        break
    print(data.decode(), end='')

mysock.close()
```

При `url = "http://google.ru"`, успешно вернуло данные:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 19:09:42 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private ...
```

---

Пример работы по шагам:

```
url = 'http://google.ru/'
result = urlsplit(url)
# SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.ru', path='/', query='', fragment='')

mysock.connect((result.netloc, 80))
# google.ru : 80

cmd = f'GET {result.path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
# b'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
```

Еще пример:

```
url = 'http://google.ru/search'
result = urlsplit(url)
# SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.ru', path='/search', query='', fragment='')
...
cmd = f'GET {result.path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
# b'GET /search HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
```

---

**UPD.**

Для работы сокетов по HTTPS нужен 443 порт, использовать [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b9603e181ba0891c1be5145d6c5a94be24089e0c/socket__tcp__examples/https__get__with_urlsplit.py#L12)

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
import socket
import ssl


socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = 'https://www.coursera.org/robots.txt'

result = urlsplit(url)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(socket, server_hostname=result.netloc)
s_sock.connect((result.netloc, 443))

cmd = f'GET {result.path} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {result.netloc}\r\n\r\n'.encode()
s_sock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = s_sock.recv(512)
    if not data:
        break

    print(data.decode(), end='')

s_sock.close()
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо большое за помощь! У меня Ваш пример с кодом сработали. А вот http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt (400 Bad request) и https://www.coursera.org/robots.txt та же ошибка.

Comment: Пробовала другие ссылки - тоже не работает.

Comment: Если вот так сделать:cmd =f'GET {url} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode(), то http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt возвращает данные.

Comment: @ВалентинаПак, тема сложнее чем кажется, для работы с https нужно обращаться к 443 порту, а не 80, плюс нужен ssl, плюс нужно указывать заголовок `Host: ` иначе защита перед сайтом не пропустил запрос. Пример накидаю в **UPD**. Для вашего скрипта нужно будет проверить https или http, и соответственно, указать правильный порт и сделать для https обертку через ssl